Unable to split the long equation
    \begin{align}
        \sin^2 \theta_{12} &= {\bigg[-2 (\cos (\sigma) \sin (2 \phi) + 1)\bigg]}\bigg/
        {\bigg[\sqrt{3} \sin (2 \phi) \sin (2 \phi') \cos (\sigma - \sigma') - 4 \cos (\sigma) \sin (\phi) \cos (\phi) \sin^2(\phi') + \sin^2(\phi) 
        \left(-\sqrt{3} \cos (\sigma') \sin (2 \phi') + \cos (2 \phi') + 2\right) + 4 \cos^2(\phi) \sin^2(\phi') - 6\bigg]} \nonumber\\
        \sin^2 \theta_{23} &= \frac{\bigg[-\sqrt{3} \cos (\sigma') \sin (2 \phi') - \cos (2 \phi') - 2\bigg]}
        {\bigg[\sqrt{3} \sin (2 \phi) \sin (2 \phi') \cos (\sigma - \sigma') - 4 \cos (\sigma) \sin (\phi) \cos (\phi) \sin^2(\phi') + \sin^2(\phi) 
        \left(-\sqrt{3} \cos (\sigma') \sin (2 \phi') + \cos (2 \phi') + 2\right) + 4 \cos^2(\phi) \sin^2(\phi') - 6\bigg]} \nonumber\\
        \sin^2 \theta_{13} &= \frac{1}{6} \bigg[\sqrt{3} \sin (2 \phi) \sin (2 \phi') \cos (\sigma - \sigma) - 4 \cos (\sigma) \sin (\phi) \cos (\phi) \sin^2(\phi') + \sin^2(\phi) 
        \left(-\sqrt{3} \cos (\sigma') \sin (2 \phi') + \cos (2 \phi') + 2\right) + 4 \cos^2(\phi) \sin^2(\phi')\bigg] \nonumber\\
    \end{align}


Welcome. // Please add the missing lines, so your code will compile when we copy it. Also often a screenshot helps to better understand your problem. Thank you

This is really more of a math problem than a TeX problem.  You have really long expressions that you're trying to fit into a page: you need to figure out how they'll fit and then tell TeX what to do.  Since you have a large expression that recurs several times, I would split that out as its own thing:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
        \sin^2 \theta_{12} &= \frac{-2 (\cos (\sigma) \sin (2 \phi) + 1)}
        {D - 6} \nonumber\\
        \sin^2 \theta_{23} &= \frac{-\sqrt{3} \cos (\sigma') \sin (2 \phi') - \cos (2 \phi') - 2}
        {D - 6} \nonumber\\
        \sin^2 \theta_{13} &= \frac{D}{6}
    \end{align}
where
\begin{multline*}
D=
\sqrt{3} \sin (2 \phi) \sin (2 \phi') \cos (\sigma - \sigma) - 4 \cos (\sigma) \sin (\phi) \cos (\phi) \sin^2(\phi') \\
+ \sin^2(\phi) \bigl(-\sqrt{3} \cos (\sigma') \sin (2 \phi') + \cos (2 \phi') + 2\bigr) + 4 \cos^2(\phi) \sin^2(\phi')
\end{multline*}

\end{document}


A few other quick notes:

\left and \right are good for quick editing, but you should switch to manual sizing once you're done
Use \bigl( instead of \big( (and all the other variations of that statement)
Ending with \nonumber\\ causes the equation number to be too low


Does the OP want to number any of the first three equations?

@Mico That is definitely unclear.  Making the minimal changes to OP's code to get it to compile does result in a single equation number, so I left it in there.

Another possibility by use of the \splitfrac and multlined of mathtools package:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
   \begin{align}
\sin^2 \theta_{12} 
    & = \frac{{-2 (\cos (\sigma) \sin (2 \phi) + 1)}}
             {\bigg[\splitfrac{
             \sqrt{3} \sin (2 \phi) \sin (2 \phi') \cos (\sigma - \sigma') 
                - 4 \cos (\sigma) \sin (\phi) \cos (\phi) \sin^2(\phi') 
                        }{
                + \sin^2(\phi) \left(-\sqrt{3} \cos (\sigma') \sin (2 \phi') + \cos (2 \phi') + 2\right) 
                + 4 \cos^2(\phi) \sin^2(\phi') - 6}\bigg]
             }                      \nonumber   \\[\jot]
\sin^2 \theta_{23} 
    & = \frac{-\sqrt{3} \cos (\sigma') \sin (2 \phi') - \cos (2 \phi') - 2}
             {\bigg[\splitfrac{
             \sqrt{3} \sin (2 \phi) \sin (2 \phi') \cos (\sigma - \sigma') 
                - 4 \cos (\sigma) \sin (\phi) \cos (\phi) \sin^2(\phi') 
                        }{
                + \sin^2(\phi) \left(-\sqrt{3} \cos (\sigma') \sin (2 \phi') + \cos (2 \phi') + 2\right) 
                + 4 \cos^2(\phi) \sin^2(\phi') - 6}\bigg]
             }                      \nonumber   \\[\jot]
\sin^2 \theta_{13} 
    & = \frac{1}{6} \left[
        \begin{multlined}
        \sqrt{3} \sin (2 \phi) \sin (2 \phi') \cos (\sigma - \sigma) - 4 \cos (\sigma) \sin (\phi) \cos (\phi) \sin^2(\phi')        \\
            + \sin^2(\phi) 
        \left(-\sqrt{3} \cos (\sigma') \sin (2 \phi') + \cos (2 \phi') + 2\right) + 4 \cos^2(\phi) \sin^2(\phi')
        \end{multlined}
                    \right]
    \end{align}
   \end{document} 


Edit:
Considered @Mico comment.

Do you need the tall square brackets in the numerators of the first two rows?

@Mico, actually no. I will remove them ASAP

Here's a variation on @Teepeemm's fine answer. I mainly suggest (a) using inline-fraction notation in the first three rows to further compactify the expressions and (b) getting rid of all unnecessary parentheses. And, I'd nest an align* environment and a multlined environment inside a gather* environment, both to get rid of all three \nonumber directives and to further "snug up" the overall appearance of the equations.

\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{mathtools}  % for '\shortintertext' macro

\begin{document}

\hrule % just to illustrate width of text block

\begin{gather*}
\begin{align*}
\sin^2\theta_{12} &= -2 (\cos\sigma \sin2\phi + 1) / D \\
\sin^2\theta_{23} &= (-\sqrt{3} \cos\sigma' \sin2\phi' - \cos2\phi' - 2) / D \\
\sin^2\theta_{13} &= D/6 + 1 
\end{align*}
\shortintertext{where}
\begin{multlined}
D=\sqrt{3} \sin2\phi \sin2\phi' \cos (\sigma - \sigma') 
   - 4 \cos\sigma \sin\phi \cos\phi \sin^2\phi' \\
   + \sin^2\phi (-\sqrt{3} \cos\sigma' \sin2\phi' 
   + \cos2\phi' + 2) + 4 \cos^2\phi \sin^2\phi' - 6 \,.
\end{multlined}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}

